# Does there exist a morphism which internally is an isomorphism but is not an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

Say that a morphism $f : X \to Y $ of a locally small category $\mathsf{C}$ is *internally-iso* if, for each object $T$ of $\mathsf{C}$, the set morphism $\mathsf{C}(T, f) : \mathsf{C}(T, X) \to \mathsf{C}(T, Y)$ is an isomorphism.

By the Yoneda lemma, a morphism which is iso is necessarily internally-iso. Does there exist an interllay-iso morphism which is not iso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach. Say that a morphism $f : X \to Y$ is

- **injective on generalized points** if for every $T$, the morphism $\text{Hom}(T, f) : \text{Hom}(T, X) \to \text{Hom}(T, Y)$ is injective, and
- **surjective on generalized points** if for every $T$, the morphism $\text{Hom}(T, f) : \text{Hom}(T, X) \to \text{Hom}(T, Y)$ is surjective.

> **Lemma:** $f$ is injective on generalized points iff it is a monomorphism.

*Proof.* This is just a matter of unwinding the definition. $\Box$

> **Lemma:** $f$ is surjective on generalized points iff it is a [split epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism), or equivalently has a section (right inverse).

*Proof.* Set $T = Y$. Surjectivity of $\text{Hom}(Y, f)$ means there is some $g \in \text{Hom}(Y, X)$ such that $fg = \text{id}_Y$, so $f$ has a right inverse. Conversely, if $f$ has a right inverse $g$, then $\text{Hom}(T, f)$ has right inverse $\text{Hom}(T, g)$, and in particular is always surjective. $\Box$

> **Theorem:** If $f$ is a monomorphism and a split epimorphism, then it is an isomorphism.

*Proof.* Let $g$ be a right inverse; we will show that it is an inverse. By definition, $fg = \text{id}_Y$, so $fgf = f$. But since $f$ is a monomorphism, it can be canceled on the left, giving $gf = \text{id}_X$. $\Box$

The point of presenting the argument this way is that "split epimorphism" can be substantially weakened (although, in general, not all the way to "epimorphism") and the statement will still be true. Note that if the proof is fully unwound then it only uses surjectivity for $T = Y$ and injectivity for $T = X$.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Yoneda embedding $Y_C\colon C\to\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$ is fully faithful, and every fully faithful functor reflects isomorphisms.

Comment: I don't understand your proof. How do you show that if $f$ is internally-iso, then $Y_C(f)$ is an iso?

Comment: @ColinTan The point is that to say "$f$ is internally iso" is to say "the natural transformation $\text{hom}_C(-,f)\colon\text{hom}_C(-,X)\to\text{hom}_C(-,Y)$ is a natural isomorphism, i.e. an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$". The natural transformation is a natural isomorphism iff each of its components is an isomorphism.

Comment: @ColinTan And, of course, $Y_C(f)=\text{hom}_C(-,f)$ (it is a definition).